# Substitue for css universal selector (*)

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the image attached, I have a wrapper `div` inside which I have `section`. 
Now, I want that all content inside `section` should have space on all sides (i.e. I want padding on all content inside `section`. I cannot do,

```
section {
  padding:20px;
}
```

because it will increase the width of `section` to 1020 + 20 (left padding) + 20 (right padding) = 1060px.

Since, direct children inside `section` are not always div (there are `aside` and `p` too), I cant do

```
section div{
 margin:20px;
}
```

Currently, I am doing

```
section > *{
    margin:20px;
}
```

So that every element takes a 20px margin from section. *This works for me* but I've heard that we should not use universal selector (*), its a performance bottleneck. Also, is this even cross browser ?

I've also thought to create a wrapper `div` inside all sections which will take all all elements inside it, so that I can do

```
section > div{
  margin:20px;
}
```

But, is this worth changing markup . Will it be so slow with universal selector ?

Comment: *"I've heard that we should not use universal selector (*), its a performance bottleneck"* - "I've heard sugar is bad for your health, so I'm trying to avoid it entirely."

Comment: And I am bad at sensing sense of humor, so I'm trying to get some serious comment :)

Comment: Well, I was pointing out the problem of over-reacting to general statements that are not false *per se* - without assessing the situation you're in. Even if something is slow, you should measure if it actually affects you negatively. Optimizing something that isn't even a problem only adds complexity.

Comment: So, it wount be so slow. Right ? :)

Comment: I added example in my unswer, explain pls, why this type of solution (most simple possible) don't works for you...

Comment: I don't know how else I can put it: *Test it and find out!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comma separated selectors, like this

```
section > div, section > aside, section > p {
    margin:20px;
}
```

Or, of course, give all the things that need margins a class, and use that class for a selector. As long as you don't use "hasmargins" for a class name...

But I'm not sure why you think that by giving the sections inside the wrapper div a padding, you'll increase the total width of the wrapper div. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is on my top list. I am gonna implement this, if none goes well. But my question was will (*) be slow even if I choose it as direct children ?

Comment: @Jashwant You mean if `div *` is faster than `div > *`? Not sure; you should test that. But I don't think it's worth losing sleep over, unless you have _very_ many elements that this selector could apply to. In most cases, things that make a site slow are graphics loading times, Flash animations and such; not this.

Comment: Point accepted. I will wait for some more time for other suggestions, before marking your answer. You and Tomalak made me realise that I am just over reacting.

Answer (score 2):

> because it will increase the width of section to 1020 + 20 (left padding) + 20 (right padding) = 1060px.

Try setup

```
section{ 
   width: 980;
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

So you setup the width of secion minus double size of padding, so finnally your section will be 1020, as you need.

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UQk9r/)

Comment: I cant do that, I need a 1020px width for `section`. Sorry, if I am not clear about that.

Comment: You will have finally 1020px width of section, after padding*2 + width will be processed!

Answer (score 1):

No.
See the Performance section from here http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: +1 for the link. I've never heard of `box-sizing: border-box` before

Answer (score 1):

Using box-sizing: border-box ( http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ ), as @Ana mentions, will actually fix your problem because you can add the padding to the parent element but not take up any extra width.

See also: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't have to do anything with the section width. And if the parent element has fixed width the child elements never surpass parent elements width.

Here is the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/HNVg9/

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HNVg9/2/) fiddle. [Box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html/)

Comment: Dipak Suryavanshi is right. If the parent's width is fixed, then the padding/ margin of the children does not influence the space taken by the parent. Content may overflow or get hidden, depending on the value of the the overflow for the parent, but it will not enlarge the space taken by the parent. Only paddings/ borders *on the parent* of set width will do that (and only if there is no box-sizing: border-box on the parrent).

Comment: @Jashwant you don't have do define width to the "section, section > div" Here the width is inherited from ".wrapper".

Comment: @Jashwant In your example fiddle, the child overflows the parent because you gave both the child and the parent the same width and then you added padding on the parent. The padding on the child has nothing to do with the fact it overflows the parent.